# Laravel deploy with EB CLI public/storage wipe out

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying my Laravel application to AWS by EB CLI. Problem with it is, it will zip everything and create a new version on the instance, removing everything user may have uploaded into public/storage folder. Usually how do we avoid this ?

Comment: You move the `storage` directory onto it's own volume and you mount independently.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Laravel. Could you mind explain how to do that steps by steps

Comment: i am also having this same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: no ... I'm asking over Laracast, follow here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-deploy-with-eb-cli-publicstorage-wipe-out